# How can I run this SQL query in Laravel? - Call to undefined function LENGTH()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to run this SQL query in many ways in laravel but it shows error.

Sql Command:

```sql
SELECT
    item_stock,
    ( LENGTH(item_stock) - LENGTH(REPLACE(item_stock, '"', '')) ) / 2
FROM
    items
```

I tried:

```php
public static function itemstockdata($item_user_id)
{
    $value = DB::table('items')->where((LENGTH(item_stock) - LENGTH(REPLACE(item_stock,'"', ''))) /2)->where('items.user_id', '=', $item_user_id)->get();
    $value = $get->count();
 
    return $value;
}
```

Im getting this error: **Call to undefined function LENGTH()**

Comment: Use `whereRaw(SOME_SQL)`

Comment: It is trying to call a PHP function `LENGTH()` which is not a function. If you don't even need the `item_stock`, you could use regular SQL similar to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE (LENGTH(item_stock) - LENGTH(REPLACE(item_stock,'"', ''))) / 2 AND user_id = ?` with minor parameter binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add it to your select clause, use the `select(column, [column, ...])`. For expressions, use either `DB::raw(expression, [bindings])` or `selectRaw(expression, [bindings])`.

You might need to escape some quotations. Also, you should give an alias to the column.

```php
public static function itemstockdata($item_user_id)
{
    $value = DB::table('items')
        ->select(
            'item_stock',
            DB::raw("( LENGTH(item_stock) - LENGTH(REPLACE(item_stock, '\"', '')) ) / 2 AS some_alias")
        )
        ->where('items.user_id', $item_user_id)
        ->get();

    return $value;
}
```

```php
$data = YourClass::itemstockdata($some_id);
echo $data->count();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo $d->some_alias;
}
```